# Prevent users from editing row field values in Pivot tables

Tags: excel, field, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am trying to find a way to prevent users from editing values in a Pivot table.

Below you can see an example of how the user can alter the table:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website, seems to meet your need.

[JetReports](http://kb.jetreports.com/article/AA-00907/0/How-to-Restrict-Users-from-Changing-or-Modifying-a-Pivot-Table.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link! However, this is not quite what I am looking for. This solution will include not being able to add additional filters, slicers, fields etc. We do want the users to be able to alter these features.